# Why isn't it possible to set up a git repo including submodules in Docker?

Tags: git, docker, docker-compose, git-submodules

Is there a proper way to initialize a git-Repository and included sub-repositories inside a docker?

As I have spent several hours on this and couldn't find a solution I switched back to the setup by shell-scripts *outside* the docker.

The idea was to have a docker that takes care of downloading the repositories including the submodules and sets the branch to *stable*.
In order to access everything with the workdir is a volume mounted by docker-compose.

The first step is downloading the main Repo which has the Dockerfile and a yaml for docker-compose. Running it will initialize the rest.
The Dockerfile looked like this:

```
WORKDIR /home/djangohome
COPY . /home/djangohome/
RUN git status
RUN git submodule init 
RUN git submodule update
```

The output on starting the docker looked fine, no errors. Yet, every time I checked the content of the subrepos they were empty.

On the other hand if I just run:

```
git submodule init 
git submodule update
```

The output is the same, but it works.

I did some research on that, it seems others came to a similar result (https://www.airpair.com/docker/posts/efficiant-development-workfow-using-git-submodules-and-docker-compose).

I still wonder why the result is despite it obviously doing *something* still just empty folders.

Comment: It *is* possible. A docker instance is just a cheap (as in low-cost and sometimes low-effectiveness, depending on how you set it up) VM a la FreeBSD "jails". The main issue with any VM is that you have to set up *enough* of it to allow it to do the same things the real machine will do, which for Git tends to be a lot: it needs a network, http and/or ssh access, CA files, a name server, and all those endless fiddly things. It's usually not worth doing because of the effort required—plus, secrets wind up in the docker FS and leak.